# Convert one line HTML pop up alert in Rails to Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to convert a working HTML dialog that I created into something more aesthetically pleasing via Twitter Bootstrap ([the seyhunak version](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)). I have the following two dialogs running so far:

```
<td><%= (@it_staff ? link_to(report.name, edit_report_path(param),
    :data => { :confirm => message}) : report.name) %></td>

<td><%= (@valid_person? link_to(t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
    edit_report_path(report), :class => 'btn btn-mini', :data => { :confirm => message}) : "") %>
```

As you can probably derive, "message" gets displayed via a hyperlink and a button. I've been browsing http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts but I can't figure out how to implement it here. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use bootstrap alerts.js plugin as opposed to a simple alert component. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

Not sure if you want something inline or as an overlay but you may want to look at popover.js or modal.js